# Create a mix of string and digit with Factory Boy in django

Tags: python, django, random, factory-boy

I want to create a mix of string and digits like this: "XL1A" or "PP25" for one field in my database.How can I do that? I'm using only uppercase letter for now.

```
class CardFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
    serial_number = FuzzyText(length=4, chars=string.ascii_uppercase)
```

Also, is there anyway to create random pattern rules for FuzzX in Factory Boy such as random IP addresses?

Comment: Both solutions from catavaran and publysher work, so thank you both. I decided to go with catavaran's solution for my code because it's less coding. But the chosen solution is a generic way of generating random data with additional rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own rules using the generic `FuzzyAttribute`. For example:

```
def generate_serial():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + random.choice(string.digits)

class CardFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
    serial_number = FuzzyAttribute(generate_serial)
```

This will generate random serials like 'Q3'. Since the `generate_serial` function is just plain Python, you can make this is as complex as you want.

Answer (score 6):

Add the `digits` to the chars list?

```
serial_number = FuzzyText(length=4,
                          chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
```

Comment: very useful answer!